# Do we also have to use the condition that $f$ is an immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

[image]
[image]
The above pages are from Lei Fu's "Algebraic Geometry".

In the  underlined sentence, in order to conclude that $g_P^\sharp$ is a monomorphism, beside the definition of scheme theoretic image, do we also have to use  the condition that $f$ is an immersion?

Comment: Could you please give the reference of the quoted text?

Comment: @Watson I have given it.